# Java Database connection error with mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I don't know why i am getting  this error infact i write code write and also add java connector in my project.
Please any one resolve my issue

```
import java.sql.*;
public class jbdcdemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            //1. Get Connection to DB
            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jbdc:msql://localhost:3306/world","root","1234");
            //2. Create a statement
            Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
            //3. Execute sql query
            ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM world.city;");      
            //4. Process the results
            while(myRs.next()){
                System.out.println(myRs.getString("Name")+", "+myRs.getString("District"));

            }
        }
        catch(Exception exc){

            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your Stack Trace , what is the actual exception !!

Comment: Please mention details about the error that you are facing.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jbdc:msql://localhost:3306/world
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at jbdcdemo.main(jbdcdemo.java:9)

Comment: @Eyal answer will solve your problem !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try fixing the connection string:

Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("**jdbc**:**mysql**://localhost:3306/world","root","1234")

Comment: @AhmedAbbas try defining  [`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm)

Comment: @AhmedAbbas Besides fixing the errors in the JDBC URL: Make sure you have the MySQL driver JAR file in your classpath.

Comment: singhakash   ! how to use this Class.forname  ?

Comment: i have the jarfile in my class path

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have semicolon for the sql statement,

Below is the correct one.

```
ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM world.city");
```